# What happens when we import an image using webpack and ES6 import?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here's a sample code (adjusted by me) from [webpack Asset Management guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images):

```
import Icon from './icon.png';

var myIcon = new Image();
myIcon.src = Icon;

document.body.appendChild(myIcon);
```

This works. Now, consider the following code:

```
import asdfasdfasdf from './icon.png';

var myIcon = new Image();
myIcon.src = asdfasdfasdf;

document.body.appendChild(myIcon);
```

This works as well.

What's going on here? What exactly is imported from a file when I import a file using webpack?

Comment: `import Icon from './icon.png'` is the same thing as saying `const Icon = require('./icon.png')`

Answer (score 0):

As you specified, there is a webpack `load` that "handles" images imports,

```
{
   test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
   use: [
      'file-loader'
   ]
}
```

That configuration tells to webpack to use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) whenever you import an image.

> `import img from './file.png'`
> Emits file.png as file in the output directory and returns the public URL
> "/public/path/0dcbbaa7013869e351f.png"